# LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception

Tags: glassfish, security, glassfish-3, jaas, jdbcrealm

I am attempting to setup container managed security with GlassFish v3.1.1 Build 12 and JSF 2.1. I keep getting the following exception for some reason and I am unable to login.

```
WARNING: WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
WARNING: Exception
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:394)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:240)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:153)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:512)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:453)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1932)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1895)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1146)
    at com.perpro.controller.MemberBean.doNavigation(MemberBean.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Security Exception
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:856)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:382)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:857)
    ... 62 more

SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletException: Exception thrown while attempting to authenticate for user: admin
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1964)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1895)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1146)
    at com.perpro.controller.MemberBean.doNavigation(MemberBean.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed login while attempting to authenticate user: admin
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1935)
    ... 51 more
```

**web.xml:**

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>UserConstraints</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/home.jsf</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
            <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>AdminConstraints</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/home.jsf</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>PerProUserAuth</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/index.jsf</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/index.jsf?error=true</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

**glassfish-web.xml:**

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
    <group-name>Internal</group-name>
    <group-name>External</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
    <group-name>Internal</group-name>
    <group-name>External</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
```

**GlassFish Admin Console Realm setup:**

**Realm Name:** PerProUserAuth
**Class Name:** com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm
**JAAS Context:** jdbcRealm
**JNDI:** MyDS
**User Table:** User
**User Name Column:** mem_id
**Password Column:** password
**Group Table:** User
**Group Name Column:** mem_status
**Digest Algorithm:** SHA-256
**Encoding:** Base64

And finally, my USER table has a mem_id of "admin" and a password that is SHA-256 base 64 encoded as (plaintext:admin): JIkcSMs4aijfwzpVjZ0MbzgWmoieGm7fxF0pTmH+cUI=

Comment: FINE: JAAS authentication aborted.
FINEST: doPasswordLogin fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess: I'd try with `jGl25bVBBBW96Qi9Te4V37Fnqchz/Eu4qB9vKrRIqRg=` as a hash for password `admin`.

```
final MessageDigest messageDigest = java.security.MessageDigest.
        getInstance("SHA-256");
final byte bin[] = messageDigest.digest(("admin").getBytes());
System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(bin));
```

(Base64 from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/))

---

Another idea: Try with hash `8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918` (password: `admin`) and HEX encoding. It was generated with:

```
final String hash = DigestUtils.sha256Hex("admin");
System.out.println(hash);
```

Comment: I used updated the password in the database and updated the Glassfish realm encoding to Base64 but I still get the same error. You did make me realize I was rehashing in a loop so +1 for that. I get the same hash you get after hashing just once. My algorithm looked pretty much exactly like yours except for the loop I had forgotten to take out. Any other ideas?

Comment: You've just updated the encoding to base64? The question said that it was base 64 :-) Anyway, check the update, please.

Comment: Thank you! Using the Apache Codec API did the trick! Not sure why the manual algorithm you and I cooked up didn't work but the DigestUtils works great. I had been switching between Base64 and Hex and updating my password in the database accordingly to match. It just so happened I was using Hex at the moment. Thanks!!!

Comment: Actually now that I look at it again, my manual method returned the same hex string as yours above: Hex.encodeHexString(btPass); Not sure what changed.

Comment: @Adam Fisher: I'm confused: Which password works with your realm setup above?

Comment: I am having issue with migration from 4.0 to 4.1.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686737/migration-from-glassfish-4-0-to-glassfish-4-1-1-jdbc-realm-issue