# javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Security Exception

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-6, jaas, jdbcrealm

I am attempting to setup container managed security with GlassFish v3.1.2 and JSF 2.1 and primeFaces 3.4.2

The value HexValue and the database match, but get the following Exception

I tried Base64 encoder but same result.
The calculated value, and password are fine, something else I missed out...
is there any other setting that I am missing out esp in glassfish or login.xhtml file

username: admin1
pass: admin

using following SHAConverter.java

```
Used org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils; for calculating HEX

final MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
final byte bin[] = messageDigest.digest((value.getBytes("UTF-8")));

final String hash = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(bin);
System.out.println("hex : " + hash);
```

```
    FINE: [Web-Security] Setting Policy Context ID: old = null ctxID = PrimeJSF-EJB-JPA-2/PrimeJSF-EJB-JPA-2
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/Login.xhtml" "POST")
FINE: [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
INFO: VALUE ------------- admin
INFO: hex : dd474e450473186ec733689b549a94a54a96f276dba76b29138c57b6afe15bf7
INFO: request.isRequestedSessionIdValid() true
INFO: user : admin1 >> dd474e450473186ec733689b549a94a54a96f276dba76b29138c57b6afe15bf7
INFO: false
FINEST: Processing login with credentials of type: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.PasswordCredential
FINE: Logging in user [admin1] into realm: myRealm using JAAS module: jdbcRealm
FINE: Login module initialized: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule
FINE: JAAS authentication aborted.
FINEST: doPasswordLogin fails
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Security Exception
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:870)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:240)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:153)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:514)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1938)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1901)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1146)
    at com.nz.simplecrud.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:83)
    at com.nz.simplecrud.controller.LoginController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.login(LoginController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.nz.simplecrud.filter.LoginPageFilter.doFilter(LoginPageFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:871)
    ... 64 more

WARNING: WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
SEVERE: IOException, Login Controller: The username or password you provided does not match our records.
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletException: Exception thrown while attempting to authenticate for user: admin1
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1970)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1901)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1146)
    at com.nz.simplecrud.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:83)
    at com.nz.simplecrud.controller.LoginController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.login(LoginController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.nz.simplecrud.filter.LoginPageFilter.doFilter(LoginPageFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed login while attempting to authenticate user: admin1
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1941)
    ... 52 more

SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1970)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1901)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1146)
SEVERE:     at com.nz.simplecrud.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:83)
SEVERE:     at com.nz.simplecrud.controller.LoginController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.login(LoginController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
SEVERE:     at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
SEVERE:     at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
SEVERE:     at com.nz.simplecrud.filter.LoginPageFilter.doFilter(LoginPageFilter.java:32)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
SEVERE: Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed login while attempting to authenticate user: admin1
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1941)
SEVERE:     ... 52 more
```

**Here is the Glassfish realmSettings**

```
Configuration Name: server-config
Realm Name: myRealm
Class Name: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm
JAAS Context: jdbcRealm
JNDI: jdbc/myDatasource
User Table: user_role_view
User Name Column: username
Password Column: password
Group Table: user_role_view
Group Table User Name Column:---
Group Name Column: rolename
Assign Groups:---
Database User:---
Database Password:---
Digest Algorithm: SHA-256
Password Encryption Algorithm:---
Encoding:Hex
Charset:UTF-8
```

**My login.xhtml**

```
<ui:define name="content">
         <h:form styleClass="loginPanelStyle">
                 <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />                        
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Login Panel
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="Username : "></h:outputText>
                <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginController.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Username!">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="1" />  
                </p:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="Password : "></h:outputText>
                <p:password id="password"  value="#{loginController.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter password!">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="1" />  
                    <f:converter converterId="com.nz.util.SHAConverter"></f:converter>
                </p:password>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs" actionListener="#{loginController.login}" type="submit" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0"></p:commandButton>

                </f:facet> 
            </p:panelGrid>
```

**My web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>Administrator</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin Area</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>Administrator</description>
            <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Manager</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Manager Area</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/manager/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>Manager</description>
            <role-name>Manager</role-name>
            <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>User</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>User Operations</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>User</description>
            <role-name>Manager</role-name>
            <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
            <role-name>User</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/Login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/Login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>Manager</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

**my glassfish-web.xml**

```
 <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
        <group-name>Administrators</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>Manager</role-name>
        <group-name>Managers</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
        <group-name>Users</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
```

[I used this post form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941713/loginexception-login-failed-security-exception), but this one had a calculation mismatch, but my problem seems to be something different then calculating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nearly the same problem as in the post you mentioned. As you can see there the hash for the password **admin** should be **8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918**  and not **dd474e450473186ec733689b549a94a54a96f276dba76b29138c57b6afe15bf7** as it is in your case.

Because the value should be a string you can yust use:

```
final String hash = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(value);
System.out.println("hex : " + hash);
```

But here is something that i don't understand:

```
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    String value = "admin";
    md.update(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    final byte bin[] = md.digest();

    System.out.println(DigestUtils.sha256Hex(bin));
    System.out.println(DigestUtils.sha256Hex(value));
```

Output is:

```
dd474e450473186ec733689b549a94a54a96f276dba76b29138c57b6afe15bf7
8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
```

But I guess both methods should return the same value...?

Comment: I changed the SHAConverter to the following
   final String hash = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(value);
   System.out.println("hex : " + hash); 

and I am getting the same   Hash for Both Database Table and Calculated SHA... 8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918 

But I am still getting the same Exception, please can you help me further drill the problem...

Comment: The Issue was fixed by removing the Converter from the login.xhtml file </br>                                                    <p:password id="password"  value="#{loginController.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter password!">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="1" />  
<!--                    <f:converter converterId="com.util.SHAConverter"></f:converter>-->
                </p:password>